# Replace HTML entities with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like a regular expression in PHP to find all HTML entities such as `"&lt;br /&gt; &lt;br /&gt; ..etc. "` in order to remove them from a long string.

Comment: Remove entirely or replace with their character values?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to solve it on your own, if so, what have you come up with?

Answer (score 20):

This one removes alpha, decimal and hex HTML entities:

```php
$text = preg_replace('/&(?:[a-z\d]+|#\d+|#x[a-f\d]+);/i', '', $text);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this regex... the [^\s]* one was capturing a whole lot other nonsense...

```
$text = preg_replace("/&(?:[a-z0-9]{2,8}|#[0-9]{2,3}+);/i", '', $text);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using strip_tags function, regex is not necessary here

Comment: Upvoting this answer; there's already a tried and tested function for this, don't make more work for yourself!

Comment: -1, `strip_tags()` removes *tags*, not html entites, such as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.